# How to have same top margins in table of contents over multiple pages

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I would like to make all pages of my table of contents have the same top margin. The default appears to be to start the first page much lower down the page as in the illustrated example. My document class is book. \addvspace was unsuccessful.

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{15pt}}
```

Suggestions?

[[My table of contents][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnhdQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnhdQ.jpg)

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example we can use to reproduce your situation. But do note that your document will look most odd if the first page of the contents is not adapted to match similar divisions of the document (chapters, sections, whatever you're using).

Comment: A quick fix, you can try `{\let\chapter\section
\tableofcontents}` or `{\let\chapter\section
\let\Large\Huge
\tableofcontents}`

Comment: You can use the afterpage package and \vspace*{} to add space to the top of the next page.  But do you really want to do this?